# Bluemix Unable to connect or ping to container

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

I have installed a container in my bluemix space. In the dashboard I see that the container is running and has a public IP address.

When I look in my command shell with the command: `cf ic ps -a` I see the following:

`CONTAINER ID    IMAGE    COMMAND    CREATED     STATUS  PORTS   NAMES
57f7363b-710        registry.ng.bluemix.net/tolsma_ns/wiccalc:v1   ""  43 minutes ago      Networking 2 minutes ago   134.168.15.165:22->22/tcp, 134.168.15.165:80->80/tcp, 134.168.15.165:587->587/tcp, 134.168.15.165:2812->2812/tcp   wiccalc`

The last line in my docker file is `CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd ", "-D"]`.

I try to ping the address `134.168.15.165` but with no success.

The weird thing is that the container stops after several minutes.

Is it possible to see what can cause that I cannot ping this IP address or why the container has been stopped?

Comment: Extra information:

I see that My container is networking and than running.  But after a while the container is networking again and then the container stop. 

With cf ic logs --recent I don;t see any logging.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a public IP you should be able to ping it. If you have just created or restarted the container it might take a couple of minutes before the ping is available (network routes).
In this moment there might be a problem with containers that brings to the stop yours and restart hanging mine. We will inform the container team about that.